# Why does ng-class="ng-app" break AngularJS?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7, angularjs

To get AngularJS to work in IE7 and IE8, I add id="ng-app" and class="ng-app" to my ng-app element:

```
<html id="ng-app" class="ng-app" ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-view></div>
</html>
```

This has always worked in the past, but now I've added class="ng-app" to two different projects, and in both the view no longer renders in any browser. Has the way to do IE7/8 compatibility changed? I'm using version 1.0.2 from the CDN.

Thank you.

Comment: Adding class="ng-app" fixed IE8 for me, so thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Edit note:* Add doctype tag will reduce some issues. 
Thanks @Mike Pateras

```
 <!doctype html>
```

*Original:*

try this

```
<html lang="en" class="ng-app:myapp" id="ng-app" ng-app="myapp" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
     <head>    
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
          <script>
            document.createElement('ng-include');
            document.createElement('ng-pluralize');
            document.createElement('ng-view');
            document.createElement('ng:include');
            document.createElement('ng:pluralize');
            document.createElement('ng:view');
          </script>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20150503/json2.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
      </head>
```

Comment: That fixes the view problem in all browsers locally, but when I point to the server from another machine using IE (Chrome works fine remotely), my view just appears as an empty <ng-view/>. Also, all versions of IE are suffering from bizarre behavior, and when I try inspect elements they have these 'jQuery1800492917332865918=3' attributes on them. Is that normal for IE?

Comment: Nope, it works fine to me. I deployed this above code on server and it works fine. I mean at least on functional-wise it works fine, you still need to fix css

Comment: My best guess will be your IE keeps the cache. You can't just hit the clear cache on dev tool. That somehow doesn't work everytime. This happened to me once .

Comment: I managed to get the debugger working a little bit (a miraculous feat in IE), but it's just saying this: [object Error]undefined. Any idea how I can get some more info? That's not too helpful...

Comment: Maybe you should try a small example to see if it works. I pretty sure this should work, because this is how I do. BTW, delete all the cache from file explorer manually.

Comment: Got it. Adding <!doctype html> got it to stop defaulting to Quirks Mode, the cause of most of my problems, and then I just had to fix a few random errors that weren't problems in the good browsers. Thank you for your help.

Comment: json2.js missing CDN path https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20150503/json2.min.js