# AngularJS tabs example and IE8

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the tabs example on the AngularJS homepage. I essentially just pulled that code out verbatim so it looks like this:

```
app.directive('tabs', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            var panes = $scope.panes = [];

            $scope.select = function(pane) {
                angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
                    pane.selected = false;
                });
                pane.selected = true;
            }

            this.addPane = function(pane) {
                if (panes.length == 0) $scope.select(pane);
                panes.push(pane);
            }
        },
        template:
            '<div class="tabbable">' +
                '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">' +
                '<li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">'+
                '<a href="" ng-click="select(pane)">{{pane.title}}</a>' +
                '</li>' +
                '</ul>' +
                '<div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>' +
                '</div>',
        replace: true
    };
});

app.directive('pane', function() {
        return {
            require: '^tabs',
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: { title: '@' },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
                tabsCtrl.addPane(scope);
            },
            template:
                '<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: selected}" ng-transclude>' +
                    '</div>',
            replace: true
        };
    })
```

This is working great except in IE8 the actual tabs that you click on to change the current tab are missing and I get this console error:

```
  Error: No controller: tabs<div class=tab-pane title="Change Log" ng-class="{active: selected}" ng-transclude>
```

What could be going wrong in IE8?

Comment: It works in every major browser I need to support except IE8. I would create a plnkr but plnkr doesn't work in IE8 either...

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184063/why-does-ng-class-ng-app-break-angularjs/13184204#13184204

Comment: I am doing document.createElement('tabs') and document.createElement('pane'). This is something I am already aware of and have other directives working beautifully in IE8. Is there something else here that I am missing?

Comment: It's hard to say. do you have ' <!doctype html>' ?

Comment: Does it have to be an element? It will work in IE8 if it's just an attribute. Change restrict to 'A' and then update your HTML to use the attribute instead of the tag name.

Comment: Changing it to an attribute does not solve the problem. It is still looking for that controller and not finding it. I actually went and copy and pasted the example from the AngularJS homepage into a new project and got the same result. What is curious is that the tabs on the AngularJS homepage DO WORK in IE8, but if I take their exact code and put it into a new project it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

On your directives, try replacing the restrict: 'E', to restrict: 'A' THEN change all directives to use attributes. Thats how I got the tabs in http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ to work in a project I'm working on that has to support IE8.