# angularjs routeprovider otherwise not working second time

Tags: internet-explorer, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have the following code

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/alljobs',{templateUrl:'alljobs.html', controller:'alljobsController'});
        $routeProvider.when('/myjobs',{templateUrl:'myjobs.html', controller:'myjobsController'});
        $routeProvider.when('/reports',{templateUrl:'reports.html', controller:'reportsController'});
        $routeProvider.when('/history',{templateUrl:'history.html', controller:'historyController'});
        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/alljobs'});
    }
]);
```

When I try to access the url "mysitelocation#/asdf" (or any text apart from the registered routes) while i am on any of the routes (/myjobs, /history, /reports or /alljobs) for the first time it redirects me to "/alljobs" as expected. But when i use the same garbage route ('mysitelocation#/asdf' in this case) the second time it just does nothing. It does not try to open a partial but it neither redirects me to "/alljobs".

I am checking on Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: If I understand correct you are already inside `/alljobs` ?

Comment: not nessecarily. this behavior is consistant irrespective of where i am /myjobs, /reports, /history!

Comment: Can you try it on a real browser (like chrome) and look at the console? How can you develop in IE9?!

Comment: It is working fine in all "real browerser" (chrome n firefox). But this is for an intranet application and client is not willing to upgrade to "real browser" so I am stuck with it.

Comment: We feel your pain IE9 bro. I'll be thinking of you today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a working solution to this for my software. I would need to look at your html, but in mine I had to add class="ng-app:myapp" to the html tag

Found it here: [Why does ng-class="ng-app" break AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184063/why-does-ng-class-ng-app-break-angularjs)