# How to get an AngularJS app working in IE8?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to get my AngularJS app available on IE8. I am using `AngularJS v1.2.16`. Utilizing (http://www.browserstack.com/) to test, I can see that it all breaks down when I set my stack to be IE8. I am following [this link from angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) to get that app to work however, when I inject this line

```
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="myApp">
```

the browser does not show any objects on the page (Only the header and footer shows) and still does not work on IE. This is because of this specific bit of code from above

```
ng-app="myApp"
```

I was wondering if this could be the cause that I cannot get my app to work on IE8. I have implemented all of the directions from directions provided by the link. However, I am not certain if I've completely fulfilled the `document.createElement();` component either. What I did was to add all of the `ng-...` tags that I've used into the list as shown.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <script>
    document.createElement('ng-include');
    document.createElement('ng-pluralize');
    document.createElement('ng-view');
    document.createElement('ng-click');
    document.createElement('ng-repeat');
    document.createElement('ng-show');

    // Optionally these for CSS
    document.createElement('ng:include');
    document.createElement('ng:pluralize');
    document.createElement('ng:view');
    document.createElement('ng:click');
    document.createElement('ng:repeat');
    document.createElement('ng:show');
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```

What could be the cause of the first issue and am I doing the second component correctly? Is there a better/simpler way to get my app functioning in IE8? If not how do I redirect/route them to a different view and lead them to [upgrading their browser](http://browsehappy.com/)? Thanks.

---

**EDIT1:**
Following KevinB's suggestion I used IE10 dev tools, switching to IE8 browser mode in order to see js errors, and I am getting these two error

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener' 
jquery.js, line 3425 character 4
SCRIPT5022: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery 
bootstrap.js, line 7 character 38
```

Suggested by livepo this seems to be an error with jQuery (2.xx does not support IE8, must be 1.11.x).

Changed the jQuery versions to 1.11.1 and got rid of the errors but the views are still messed up. This is because of [bootstrap compatibility](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support) with IE8.

**Conclusion:** This one questions lead to many different questions and so will open a new question for further discussion. Thank you for everyone's support on this.

Comment: Are you using an older version of AngularJS? **the most recent version(1.3) has no support for IE8.**

Comment: My guess is that guide is written for angular 1.2 and not 1.3

Comment: @KevinB The most recent stable version (1.2.X) does. The most recent unstable version (1.3.X) does not. Luckily, the Angular guide explicitly mentions the differences in 1.3 and 1.2 that the OP hopefully noticed

Comment: How long do people expect us to keep supporting IE8?!

Comment: @Jonathan I know right, but I'd still like to find a solution if I can. @KevinB I am using `AngularJS v1.2.16`.

Comment: @Jonathan Probably as long as MS supports Windows7, 14 Jan 2020?

Comment: @stcho i think you've over-done the createElement, though i doubt that is the cause of your problem. You only need to do that for elements, not attributes. For example, `<ng-view></ng-view>` but not `<div ng-repeat></div>`

Comment: @KevinB I see, yea that is what I thought as well but when it still didn't work I thought I'd try them all. Still wasn't the solution.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the F12 console? Have you added polyfills for methods you may be using in your controllers such as `[].forEach`? have you removed all of the `console.*` calls from your code?

Comment: I'm in it right now but where is IE8 dev tool's equivalent to Chrome `console`? I've never used IE dev tools before.

Comment: press F12 to open Ie8 devtools.

Comment: I am in the dev tool screen already but I don't see any errors, the screen shows html, css, profiler, ..., I see multiple tabs, but no error messages

Comment: If you have access to a newer version of IE, you can use it's devtools to test in IE8 mode. It's not perfect, but it will at least point out any js errors.

Comment: Awesome we're making progress. Using IE10 dev tools and switching to IE8, I am getting two errors `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener' 
jquery.js, line 3425 character 4
SCRIPT5022: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery 
bootstrap.js, line 7 character 38`

Comment: Yup, jQuery 2.x is the culprit. you can safely switch that right over to 1.11.1 without worrying about conflicts.

Comment: Did that, but the views are still messed up. Maybe bootstrap version computability?

Comment: I suggest asking a new question, this question is starting to change from one issue to a completely new one.

Comment: @Kevin B Yea I agree.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this SO article will help. [Why does ng-class="ng-app" break AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184063/why-does-ng-class-ng-app-break-angularjs)

It suggests to add ***class="ng-app:myApp"*** to the html tag. Please give the advice in this article a try and see if it helps.

Please be aware too, that the only reason you would need the document.createElement() calls is only if you are using custom tags, such as

```
<my-custom-tag></my-custom-tag>
```

Using

```
<div my-custom-tag></div>
```

will eliminate the need for that whole section.

**EDIT:** Forgot 'Code' sections

Comment: Hi livepo, I've tried your solution however still a no go. I am not seeing any errors in the console either.I am getting the same error Mike got in the linked thread. Quote- "That fixes the view problem in all browsers locally, but when I point to the server from another machine using IE (Chrome works fine remotely), my view just appears as an empty <ng-view/>. Also, all versions of IE are suffering from bizarre behavior, and when I try inspect elements they have these...

Comment: Hey stcho, he fixed the issue by adding <!doctype html> to the top of his page. Did you include that aswell? Quote - "Got it. Adding <!doctype html> got it to stop defaulting to Quirks Mode, the cause of most of my problems, and then I just had to fix a few random errors that weren't problems in the good browsers. Thank you for your help"

Comment: I just noticed your last comment. Looks to me like that is an error with jQuery (2.xx does not support IE8, you must use 1.11.x).

Comment: Ahh I see ok. Currently I'm using v2.1.1. I don't know if it'd be worth it to change jQuery's version to v1.x.x  due to the fact that other libraries might be dependent on the newer versions of jQuery.

Comment: jQuery 1.11 and 2.1 have the exact same API, the only difference is support for old IE versions. You should be fine.

Comment: Ok I will try it out!

Comment: Changed the jQuery versions and got rid of the errors but the views are still messed up. Do you think it might be bootstrap version compatibility?

Comment: They have the exact API, yes, but the 'support' is the whole issue. If you look at line 1071 in jqeury 1.11, you can see an example that it is actually checking if parent.AddEventListener exists, and if it doesn't it will use the IE8 equivelent which is parent.attachEvent. In jQuery 2.xx there are a couple spots where if (document.addEventlistener) is not present and that's where he is erroring out at. (Line: 3425, 3428, 4763)

Comment: @stcho I think you just fixed one of many problems. :) take note of the IE8 support of bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support

Comment: Haha yea I think I'm starting to realize that. Thanks I'll check it out.